# Network load balancer real life examples?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

Even after a lot of googling, I could not find a simple answer to this question. All I could find was it's layer 4 load balancer that can handle millions of requests per second, and support for static/elastic ip. Could someone please give me an example where network load balancers are used in real life? A simple use case. When to pick network load balancer over application load balancer?

Comment: why the down vote? It's a noob question.

Comment: Good question. I will upvote to balance the vote count ◡̈

Comment: I didn't downvote, but FYI the definition of a down-vote is _"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"_. Also, some people just don't like non-programming questions appearing on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 18):

When compared to an Application Load Balancer a simple explanation goes like this: Network Load Balancer is used anywhere where the application behind the balancer doesn't work over HTTP(S), but uses some other protocol. Including, but not limited to:

- Legacy applications that implement custom protocol.
- NTP servers.
- SMTP server.
- Database servers.
- MQTT brokers.
- High performance queue servers (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ etc.).
- Message processing applications (think Kafka and Co.).

Answer (score 14):

I would like to complement @Sergey list with few more scenarios where NLB is useful:

- NLB provides **static IP** address, ALB does not. So use it when you require a static IP for your LB. Similarly, it is the only balancer that can use **Elastic IP addresses**.
- Use NLB when you require **end-to-end SSL encryption**. ALB will always terminate SSL connection, which may be not desired due to strict security requirements.
- NLB is the only balancer type that can be used for API Gateway [VpcLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) or [VPC PrivateLink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/endpoint-service.html) technologies.
- NLB does not have Security Groups.

Comment: NLBs support security groups now. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/08/network-load-balancer-supports-security-groups/